# pg_config executable not found using django-redshift-backend

Tags: django, amazon-redshift

I am having trouble installing redshift on my django app.
When I am running

```
pip3 install django-redshift-backend
```

I get the error pg_config executable not found. My version of pip is 9.0.1 and I don't know why I'm having this error.
Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by reinstalling libpq-dev.
It may help people facing the same issue.